# Katalon external library

Tags: katalon-studio

I'm trying to use my own code for Katalon as a library.
My own code has imports like this

```
from com.test.page import Page
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import robot.utils.asserts as asserts
```

This file is totally executable on its own when I'm using IDE, but when I tried to import it to Katalon, I got exception message like this

```
ImportError: No module named test
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Katalon studio Java jar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51963223/katalon-studio-java-jar-files)

Answer (score 1):

In order to use external references, you should go to the IDE and select 
Project -> Settings -> External Libraries

On the window add your jar file.

Remember that you also need to check if the .classpath file is updated accordingly if you use git (it's on the .gitignore list, so needs to be updated manually)

Answer (score 0):

Do you put your .jar in Drivers folder inside your project?
Write `import com.test.page.Page` instead of yours

Comment: single line solution should be in comment.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to keep all jar files is to create a folder in Katalon folder structure and store all jar files in it. When you commit Katalon project into a source repositories like Github and SVN, don't forget to commit jar files as well so that the references given in the code will no throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- put additional jars in lib directory like "C:\Users[ME].katalon\8.2.0\Katalon_Studio_Engine_Windows_64-8.2.0\configuration\resources\lib\jsch-0.1.54.jar".
- restart katalon then in your script, use `import com.jcraft.jsch.*;`