# Katalon Studio and Git SubModules: how to import external common libraries into a katalon project

Tags: git, git-submodules, katalon-studio

We are currently using Katalon Studio as a Test Automation Framework. We use Git to version and distribute the test project over to the test benches.

Many of our test solution make use of common keyword libraries, and it doesn't make sense to version them multiple times in each git repository.

Instead, we would like to move the common libraries to a single shared repository, which would then be incldued as submodule in the Katalon distributed project(s).

Since this approach appears to be fairly new in the community, and seen the [proposed approach](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/git-integration.html) not really accounting for this level of detail, I am wondering about the impact of the submodule on the project(s). Is there any un-official documentation on this that I cannot find? Or, is there a built-in alternative to achieve the same result?

<sub>[This tutorial](https://www.toolsqa.com/katalon-studio/import-external-library-to-katalon-studio-project/) on how to import external libraries in Katalon doesn't account for mainteneance and updates of the external library outside the project's git repository.</sub>

<sub>Common keywords, as of now, are not compiled into a loadable .jar file, so the canonical [import jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51963223/katalon-studio-java-jar-files) approach is not what we are looking for. Apparently, they are stored as Groovy files, so that each tester can access and edit them on the fly. I don't really like the approach.</sub>